# Python Socket message are truncated

Tags: python, sockets, irc

I created a bot which connect to the chan through socket like this

```
socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.connect((network,port))
irc = ssl.wrap_socket(socket)
```

Then i send some message when some actions are triggered, this works quite well but there is one messsage which is truncated, and my script don't return any error. Here is the code of this message :

```
def GimmeUrlInfos(channel,message):
  link = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', message)
  response = urllib2.urlopen(link[0])
  html = BeautifulSoup(response.read())
  urlTitle = html.find('title')
  irc.send("PRIVMSG %s Link infos:" % (channel) + urlTitle.contents[0] + "\r\n" )
```

The script look in the message if there is a link inside, if yes beautifulSoup get the title of the HTML page. So it's returns something like: `Link infos: THis is the Title of the Webpage you give in your message`.

But it only returns

> Link

at the channel. Is there some limitations or something ?

Comment: Which part of this is causing a problem, and what exactly is the problem? You mean the `irc.send` sends the string `"Link"` instead of the one you asked it to? Or it only sends `"PRIVMSG #foochanHtml Title Link"` and doesn't send the rest of the line? Or something different?

Comment: On top of explaining the problem further, please print out the string you're trying to send and make sure it's what you want, and also print out the return value from `irc.send`.

Comment: I add some explanation in the question :)

Comment: You still haven't printed out the string inside `irc.send`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my next guess, now that you've given us a little more information:

Your string looks like this:

```
PRIVMSG #mychannel Link infos: Title of Page\r\n
```

In IRC, arguments are split on spaces, except that an argument that starts with a colon can include spaces, and runs to the end of the line. So, your target is `#mychannel`, your message is `Link`, and the whole rest of the line is a bunch of extra arguments that are ignored.

To fix this, you want to send:

```
PRIVMSG #mychannel :Link infos: Title of Page\r\n
```

So, change your code like this:

```
irc.send("PRIVMSG %s :Link infos:" % (channel) + urlTitle.contents[0] + "\r\n" )
```

For more details on how messages are formatted in RFC, and on the `PRIVMSG` command, see [2.3.1 Message format in 'pseudo' BNF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1459.html#section-2.3) and [4.4.1 Private messages](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1459.html#section-4.4.1) in RFC 1459.

Comment: @x_vi_r: For anything non-trivial like this, you might want to consider using an IRC library like [`irc`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/irc), or one of the many bot frameworks out there. Either way, it'll make everything easier, and make mistakes like this (which are very easy to make) impossible.

Comment: @x_vi_r: Sure. Sometimes having to learn something as complicated as the RFC-1459 IRC protocol at the same time gets in the way of learning Python, but sometimes it gives you the motivation you need to learn Python; whatever works for you is good.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from your question, but I think you wanted to send something like this:

```
PRIVMSG #mychannel Link infos: Title of Page\r\n
```

… and actually only sent something like this:

```
PRIVMSG #mychannel Link
```

One possible explanation of this is that [`socket.send`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send) and [SSLSocket.send](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send) don't necessarily send the entire string you give it. That's why they returns a number of bytes sent. If you want to block until it's able to send the whole string, use `sendall` instead.

Comment: I add some explanation in the question :) I try sendall but it returns the same